# Determine segment selection on a circle

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, geometry, trigonometry

My project consists of a wheel in which a user can add segments to; think of it as a wheel of fortune if you will. These segments can either be of equal weighting or a custom percentage.

Now for my problem. I can't figure out an efficient way of adding touch detection so that a user can click a specific segment and edit it's properties. I am writing the prototype in XNA so I thought of defining a boundary and checking for any touches within that space. Another method I considered is by calculating the angle from 0 to the touch location and then calculating which segment that would fall in.

Unfortunately, that's where I got stuck. If anyone could suggest a more effective method or point me in the right direction in terms of code it would be most appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Detecting touch? Detecting which segment of a circle a point lies in? Editing its “properties”? Writing XNA?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my first post, I'm having trouble detecting which segment of the circle the mouse click lies in.

Comment: As I wrote below, do you know the length of each arc and the radius of your wheel, or the angle of every slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to choose the second way you've written:
"calculating the angle from 0 to the touch location and then calculating which segment that would fall in".
You only need to know the length of each arc and the radius of your wheel, or just the angle that every slice will fill, and then you're done.
I don't understand if it has to spin, too, but in that case you just have to keep trace of the rotation when detecting the `TouchLocation`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it's going the be the best way. Like I said above, each segment has a percentage value of the circle so I can easily retrieve each segments angle.